# How to add custom fields in Salesforce Community Template

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-template

I am trying to create a form using Salesforce Community Template. I know there is an option of creating web-to-lead form but unfortunately I have been asked to create form using community.

I have selected customer service template(suggest me if I should use some other template to just create a form). Out of that form, a case needs to be created in Salesforce. In order to achieve that, I thought of creating a Case form in the template and add extra fields that I wanted for the form but I don't know to add custom fields to it? Right now it just shows standard case form fields as shown in the attached pic.[image: cu]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the community component is tied to the default NewCase global action and its associated layout .

If you navigate to set up >Global actions > NewCase > Edit layout ,you will notice only the fields shown in screen shot are available

[image]

You can drag more fields to the global action to fix this .

Alternatively if you edit the component in community builder you can associate the component to another custom action that you might have created for New Case .

Comment: Ok I added some fields to new case global action and the fields started appearing. Thanks for the help. Do you know how can I make the case form appear on the front page of community template? Right now it seems to be on an entirely different page.

Comment: Yes edit the page via community builder  and drag the component

Comment: Not sure if I understood. But I tried dragging the create case form from the components list to the front page and it gives this error "To create cases, an action must be specified by the administrator"